Is it normal for a MAX232 chip to test positive for continuity between T1OUT and R1IN when powered?
I have noticed, on my MAX232 chip, that when the IC is powered, a continuity test between the T1OUT and R1IN pins tests positive. But not when it is not powered.
Is this normal?

What information in the data sheet have you looked at that might establish a reason?

How exactly do you perform continuity tests on powered boards?

If you have a second meter handy, you may find it instructive to measure the voltage between these pins, as-is, and with the continuity tester connected to them.

Sounds normal.
Any result should be OK, because trying to measure continuity between two pins of an IC with some arbitrary meter is meaningless - unless you are using resistance measurement to detect fully shorted or fully open connections.
If you simply get a result of "yes" and "no" for the continuity, you have no clue how the continuity is measured and how the measurement result is interpreted into "yes" and "no".
Fortunately, for most meters, they measure resistance, and they produce the result based on the measurement being above or below some threshold resistance in order to beep or not.
Unfortunately, different meters use different thresholds so some meters will give different results.
Another thing is that the meters try to measure the resistance between terminals based on applying some test current and measuring voltage (or the other way around). Different meters will also apply different test voltages or currents so they also give different results.
The only problem is that you are trying to measure a semiconductor device which is not a resistor, so the measured resistance is just a result of showing a value based on the voltage and current, so there simply is no resistance.
And since you measured a powered on a live circuit that outputs voltages between chip pins, your meter cannot even perform the measurement due to the external voltages and currents caused by the measured chip, it will throw off the meter measurement result.
The only giveaway is that you can't use continuity or resistance measurements on live circuits, and maybe measuring continuity or resistance of semiconductors have little use.
The only use is that if the meter measures abouy 0 ohms with an unpowered circuit, it means that the pins are likely shorted together, either intentionally by design such as a PCB copper trace, or something has damaged and made a short circuit.
